# Grant option error with view

Tags: oracle, view, schema, sql-grant

I have schema_A.table_A and I would like to create view schema_B.view_B as `select ... from schema_A.table_A`. I had granted `GRANT SELECT on schema_A.table_A to schema_B WITH GRANT OPTION` but when I'm trying to create the view, I'm getting error

> ORA-01720: grant option does not exist for schema_A.table_A.

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: which user you run this grant script

Comment: I have admin user which I'm using to do everything.

Comment: so what is the schema_a and table_a , they are system tables?

Comment: Perform with SCHEMA_A `select * from user_objects where object_name = 'TABLE_A'` - you'll see that the `OBJECT_TYPE` is not a table with high probability...